# Cannot stop or kill Docker image

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am running boot2docker on my Windows 7.
Inside the VM image I am trying to stop all of the Docker images, however I get an error:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker images
REPOSITORY           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
svendowideit/samba   latest              ce8e4e03282a        8 days ago          252 MB
hello-world          latest              e45a5af57b00        13 days ago         910 B
busybox              latest              4986bf8c1536        13 days ago         2.433 MB
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker stop e45a5af57b00
Error response from daemon: No such container: e45a5af57b00
FATA[0000] Error: failed to stop one or more containers
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker kill e45a5af57b00
Error response from daemon: No such container: e45a5af57b00
FATA[0000] Error: failed to kill one or more containers
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking at images and trying to stop container. They are not the same. docker ps will give you running containers, docker ps -a will give you all containers.

Images are just images of filesystem which used by docker run command. docker run creates container which could be stopped or removed (docker rm) but you rarely need to remove image (docker rmi).

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                        TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
ubuntu                            latest              5506de2b643b        11 weeks ago        199.3 MB

$ docker run ubuntu
$ docker run ubuntu
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
037b45371358        ubuntu:latest                       "bash"                 2 seconds ago       Exited (0) 2 seconds ago                        goofy_yalow         
7a1f93ed42b3        ubuntu:latest                       "bash"                 4 seconds ago       Exited (0) 3 seconds ago                        admiring_yalow
```

As you see ids are different - these containers already exited - so they could not be stopped, they could be inspected, removed, restarted. If you don't need container when process there is finished - you could use --rm option:

```
docker run --rm ubuntu
```

then container will be removed automatically when it is stopped.

Answer (score 11):

To stop all docker containers:

`$ docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`

Then to remove all docker containers:

`$ docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`

To remove all docker images:

`$ docker rmi $(docker images -q)`

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan has stated the how to stop all docker containers, however you will need to be using a Git Bash or Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) to allow that to work.

To install WSL see this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

Using just the normal windows command line will not work.

Comment: In January 2015, WSL didn't exist to run docker, so I don't believe this applies to the OP's issue.